# Парсинг баланса в телегу

Tags: парсер, telegram-bot, пароль, веб-сайт

Нужно, чтобы бот брал инфу с личного кабинета и выводил баланс, но вместо этого он пишет так:

> Ваш баланс: []

```
import requests
import telebot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

url = 'https://stat.system-ural.ru/'
login = 'se0017'
password = '...'

session = requests.Session()
r = requests.get(url)


html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')


for el in html.select('table'):
    summa = el.select('.td.utm-cell')



@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваш баланс: {summa}")


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Это значит, что элемент `table.td.utm-cell` не найден

Comment: @RomanKonoval да, оказалось что он не проходит дальше страницы залогинится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи

```
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

authdata = {'login': 'se0017', 'password': '...'}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.post('https://stat.system-ural.ru/', data=authdata)
parsedata = session.post('https://stat.system-ural.ru')

html = BS(parsedata.content, 'html.parser')
items = html.find_all("td", class_="utm-cell")
kot = []
 
for item in items:
        a = item.text
        kot.append(a)
        
summ = kot[7]        

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваш баланс: {summ}")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

> Верстальщик этого сайта скорее всего был на грибах XD

Comment: ты самый лучший человек!!!!!!!